# JSF 2 Submitting a form

Tags: jsf-2, form-submit

I have this Facelet codes:

```
<h:inputText id="searchtext" value="#{SearchBean.input}" />
<h:commandButton value="#{msg.BUTTON_SEARCH_LABEL}" title="#{msg.BUTTON_SEARCH_LABEL}"
  action="#{SearchBean.Submit}" />
```

**SearchBean** has the following:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "SearchBean")
@RequestScoped
public class SearchBean implements Serializable
{
    private String input = null;
    private Boolean submitted = false; 

    public String getInput() {
       return input;
    }

    public boolean getSubmitted() {
       return submitted;
    }      

    public void setInput(String input) {
       this.input = input;
    }

    public void setSubmitted(Boolean submitted) {
       this.submitted = submitted;
    }

    public String Submit() {
       System.out.println(">>> SUBMITTED <<<"); 
       submitted = true;
       return "";
   }    
}
```

The SearchBean's method is called in **BookService** bean as follow:

```
@Stateless
public class BookService()
{
    @Inject
    private SearchBean searchBean;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init()
    {
       Boolean isSearch = isSubmitted();
       if (isSearch) {
          // some codes
       } else {
          // other codes
       }
    }

    public Boolean isSubmitted() {
       System.out.println("STATUS: " + searchBean.getSubmitted()); 
       return searchBean.getSubmitted();
    }       
}
```

When I submit the form, the status return by SearchBean's **getSubmitted()** method always return **false**. I would expect this to return **true** when the form is submitted. I don't know what to do.

Is **FlashScoped** the only usable option with form submission in JSF 2? Any expert care to comment.

Answer (score 1):

Use @ViewScoped and return null in your submit() method:

```
public String Submit() {
       submitted = true;
       return null;
}
```

Attributes within a bean in view scope will persist until the user navigates to a new view. Returning null from a bean method will reload the same view and keep the bean's state.

**UPDATE:** First question back: Is you BookService bean called from the same view? If not, the ViewScope will not work. You have to put the submitted variable in session scope instead.

Make sure that your submit method is called (debug with a breakpoint inside the method) and make sure that your form elements are enclosed by `<form> ... </form>`.

Comment: Thanks. I tried your suggestion with @ViewScoped but I'm still getting false returned for the getSubmitted() method.

Comment: Are you sure that your Submit method is called? You could debug and set a breakpoint into the method. Are your form elements enclosed by `<form>`..`</form>` tags? Updated my answer.

Comment: I have a debug statement in the Submit method and I can see that the statement is printed in the Console window so I know it's been submitted. And yes, I do have <h:form> tags surrounding the Facelet codes above and BookService is called in the same view. Also, I have updated the BookService bean above so you can see what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Don't have much experience with injection. Are you sure that it is the same instance injected into your BookService bean and called from your view?

Comment: I can see the debug statement from SearchBean's `Submit` method so I know that the same SearchBean instance has been injected into BookService. Would the @PostConstruct-annotated method 'init()' above get executed **before** the SearchBean is injected?

Answer (score 0):

@RequestScoped means that the context is destroyed at the end of the servlet request.

Try @ViewScoped of @FlashScoped. For the difference: [what's new in jsf 2](http://andyschwartz.wordpress.com/2009/07/31/whats-new-in-jsf-2/#scopes)

Comment: I tried to include javax.faces.bean.ConversationScoped in the project but Eclipse chuck a fit as it cannot resolve the class. Where can I find the jar that ConversationScoped class resides. Thanks

Comment: You changed your answer from the last time. Anyway, as per my comment with @Matt, using @ViewScoped still returns false for the getSubmitted() method.

Comment: @user463053: I did indeed. Made the wrong assumption in my first answer. Are you sure the form gets submitted?

Comment: I have a debug statement in the Submit method and I can see that the statement is printed in the Console window so I know it's been submitted.

Comment: I have updated the BookService bean above so you can see what I'm trying to do. Hopefully, it makes sense. -:)